# What does the word ES/QS mean in Intel CPU model names?

Tags: cpu, intel

I have a question about this CPU model name: "i9-9900K ES/QS".  What does the ES/QS mean? I found its prices cheap.

I want to know if there is a difference between these processors and the normal Intel processors sold in retail boxes, like the standard [i9-9900K](https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/products/sku/186605/intel-core-i99900k-processor-16m-cache-up-to-5-00-ghz/specifications.html) Coffee Lake.

Answer (score 1):

ES (Engineering Sample)
QS (Qualification Sample)

cheap i think bcz they dont OC (Overclock) well

**Source:**

- https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000056642/processors/intel-core-processors.html
- https://linustechtips.com/topic/1169418-genuine-intel-cpu-0000/
- https://linustechtips.com/topic/1161400-9900k-es-vs-9700k/

Comment: Thank you my friend for the information. I was searching for it and couldn't find it. Also, are there any other terms related to processors?

Comment: Got no idea, That's what i have come across